# Email composer show in landscape mode when restrict application in portrait mode (android +phonegap )

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I restricted my application on portrait mode in phonegap.But when I used email composer plugin and open email composer the it show in landscape mode ? why is there any way to show email composer in only portrait mode.?

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you restricted particularly an Activity to be in a portrait mode, it will be apply only your SplashScreenActivity. For other Activity it will remain as default.
If you want this for other activity also you have to write

```
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in all activity,

**Try This**

```
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: is this applicable in phonegap .I am not using native application.i am using HTML%